# Building nginx deb package with custom openssl

Tags: compiling, nginx, openssl, source-packages

I'm trying to build nginx packages from a deb package source (from the popular, semi-official [nginx mainline PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/development)) but linked to [an openssl fork](https://github.com/PeterMosmans/openssl) that contains ChaCha20 and Poly1305 additions.

I configured openssl with `./config no-ssl2 no-ssl3 shared -fPIC` (I also set `CFLAGS="-fPIC"`), which worked and built successfully, and I can see `-fPIC` appearing in all the compilation steps during the build. When I build the nginx package with `dpkg-buildpackage -b` pointing at it (I edited `auto/options` and set `OPENSSL=/home/admin/openssl`), I get this error:

```
objs/ngx_modules.o \
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -ldl -lpthread -lpthread -lcrypt -lpam -lexpat -lpcre /root/openssl/.openssl/lib/libssl.a 
/home/admin/openssl/.openssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl -lz -lxml2 -lxslt -lexslt -lgd -lGeoIP \
-Wl,-E /usr/bin/ld: /home/admin/openssl/.openssl/lib/libssl.a(s23_meth.o): 
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/admin/openssl/.openssl/lib/libssl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, since I did build it with `-fPIC`?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make this work. It turns out that when building nginx this way, it does not use the pre-built openssl libraries, but compiles them anew, and at this point it's missing the configure options that I'd provided in the separate build. I spotted an `OPENSSL_OPT` property in the `auto/options` file. So the options I set in there were:

```
USE_OPENSSL=YES
OPENSSL=/root/openssl
OPENSSL_OPT="no-ssl2 no-ssl3 -fPIC"
```

With those set, the compile completed successfully, and I was able to install the resulting packages.